# Core data: missing variable binding for (null)

Tags: objective-c, core-data, prefetch

In Core Data, I have a computing case requiring batch faulting. I use the following method to do it and I prefetch some linked entities at the same time. Most of the time everything works but occasionally some users get a crash:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
missing variable binding for (null)
```

Here is the method I use to do this:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [CoreDataWrapper fetchRequestForEntity:entityName inManagedObjectContext:aContext];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self IN %@", entities];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
[request setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:entityPaths];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sortKey ascending:ascending];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSError *error;
NSArray *results = [aContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

return results;
```

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure that objects in `entities` belongs to `aContext`?

Comment: They come from `NSSet *sis = [sessions valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.sessionSerie"]` where `sessions` is an array of `NSManagedObject`

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I need help with a problem with the same error message, and looking for ideas on how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

after contacting Apple for this, here is what I've been answered:

1. Only use queue-based contexts, meaning to call - (instancetype)initWithConcurrencyType: with either NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType or NSMainQueueConcurrencyType whenever you need to create a NSManagedObjectContext instance.
2. Wrap the code accessing the context and its objects with performBlock(AndWait).
3. If you need to pass Core Data objects across different contexts, use NSManagedObjectID, rather than NSManagedObject.

In my case I had an old way of using core data in background threads so I needed to use performBlock in my code.

That's it!

Comment: Could you elaborate just a little more - with some code snippets for the "wrongs" and the "rights" in your code after the fix? I experience similar issue, but I do not (directly) have any of the mentioned things - I only work through one MOC (although my base document class may have more MOCs for saving). I never call anything explicitly on background threads... So some sample code would help